# Does Eigen::EigenSolver work on an object of class SparseMatrix?

Tags: rcpp, eigen, eigenvalue

Does `Eigen::EigenSolver` work on an object of class `SparseMatrix`? 
In particular, I am using RcppEigen.

Secondly, which algorithm is used? Is it the same QR algo as in EISPACK, LAPACK, Wilkinson (1965) ...etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. EigenSolver only works with dense matrices, not with sparse matrices.
2. Yes, EigenSolver uses the QR algorithm. It's very similar to the one in EISPACK; the [documentation](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox-devel/classEigen_1_1EigenSolver.html) says: *The implementation is adapted from JAMA (public domain). Their code is based on EISPACK.* I believe LAPACK uses a slightly different variant of the QR algorithm with multiple shifts.